# Flex Builder: src location

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

how can I change the location of the src folder?

Right now I can just move the src folder from the navigator to some other location, but it's not being referenced as the src folder. (it doesn't have the square-ry icon on the folder icon)

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

Ah figured it out.
It's from the "Project" tab then go to "Properties" then to "ActionScript Build Path".

Thanks,
Tee